# How to align left dl content?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue when using Bootstrap's `dl` with the `dl-horizontal` class. In the `xs`, `md` and `lg` viewports the `dl`'s descriptions are displayed properly. However, in the `sm` viewport, the `dl`'s content leaves its parent's boundary.

Here's the `xs` viewport.

[image: XS viewport]

Then the larger ones...

[image: LG and larger]

And the problem appears with the `md` viewport.

[image: MD viewport]

Here's the code related to that `div`:

```
    <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    Stats
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Advanced</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <dl class="dl-horizontal text-muted">
                        <dt>
                            Nodes:
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            7
                        </dd>
                        <dt>
                            Bandwidth:
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            3 kbps
                        </dd>
                        <dt>
                            Average hops:
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            3
                        </dd>
                        <dt>
                            Latency:
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            100 ms
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this property to erase the `text-align: center` property of dt :

```
.dl-horizontal dt { text-align: left; }
```

[See it here](http://www.bootply.com/Ly1cfTtb3P)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `dt` element's style `width: auto;`

Comment: Merely changing `dt` width won't be enough, because `dd`s have `margin-left` set

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom style for dt and dd that resets default behaviour of style as others suggested.

```
.dl-horizontal > dt.left {
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: auto;
}

.dl-horizontal > dd.left {
    margin-left:0;
}
```